# Keep url encoded while using URI class

Tags: c#, .net, web, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get public profile information from LinkedIn. To achieve this I have to provide
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=public-profile-url, where public-profile-url MUST be URL encoded.

The issue is that .NET classes such as HttpClient, WebRequest etc use Uri class which seems to "canonize" the provided URL, so that I can't get the proper formatted request sent.

The URI must be:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.linkedin.com%2fin%2fiftachragoler

but is:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http://www.linkedin.com/in/iftachragoler

In this way, I get 'Bad Request' from LinkedIn.

Is there any way I can have Uri/UriBuilder not to decode that URL?

Comment: Are you doing something like `"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=" + uri.ToString()`? Then the URI class is doing exactly what it should do and you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=" + Url.Encode(profileUrl), and then passing that to DotNetOpenAuth which itself passing it to UriBuilder.

Comment: There is no Url class in .NET. Please show the actual code you're using.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: var linkedInRequestUrls = string.Format(LinkedInRestApi.PeoplePersonByPublicUrl, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is report about that on Microsoft connect. By default escaped slashes not allowed due to security reasons.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94109/

Cites from there:

> I try to use the LinkedIn api, for which I need the following link:
>   http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fyourlinkedinname:public
>
> As you can see the url field needs to be escaped. How to solve this?

Answer:

> We currently don't allow escaped slashes and dots to appear in the
>   path because this is a common way to attacker a server when the URI
>   scheme supports path compression.

But there is tab with workarounds. One of them for .NET 4 is to add app.config:

For .NET 4.0, you can control this through the config file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882619.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656539.aspx

```
<configuration>
<uri>
    <schemeSettings>
     <clear/>
     <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
</uri>
</configuration>
```

For .NETs before .NET was constructor for Uri class with parameter "dontEscape". For .NET 4 it's obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, man! This did the trick. Having added that section to Web.config, I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you double escape it?

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%253a%252f%252fwww.linkedin.com%252fin%252fiftachragoler
```