# Keep URL encoded while using URI class for Linkedin API

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, linkedin-api

I am trying to make a request to LinkedIn using a public URL. The problem with URL encoding has been documented many times before on this site, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11034569/2302862).

Windows phone developers cannot use the workarounds documented so far, because:

1. Config files - not relevant to phone projects.
2. Reflection - permission problems.

Has any windows phone developer found a way across this barrier?